# Como alterar a escala do eixo y em um gráfico de linha

Tags: r, plot, gráfico

Estou tentando plotar um gráfico em que os pontos no eixo y variam em casas decimais mas não consegui ajustar a escala do eixo para que varie em casas decimais também.

```
t_mean = c(30.24, 30.73, 30.94, 31.97, 31.28, 31.84, 31.56, 32.00)
time   = c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14)

plot=(t_mean~time, type ="l",  ylim=c(30.0,32), yaxt ="n")
axis(2, at=c(30.0:32.0))
```

Comment: Nota: `m:n` é sempre um vetor de inteiros, `c(30.0:32.0)` não está errado mas não precisa de `c()` e descarta as decimais. Muito mais legível será `30:32`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isso é criando um vetor com a função `seq`. Como o nome sugere, a função `seq` cria uma sequência de números. Basta informar o valor inicial, o valor final e o incremento. No exemplo abaixo, eu crio uma sequência que começa em 30 e vai até 32, aumentando de 0.1 em 0.1:

```
seq(from=30, to=32, by=0.1)
 [1] 30.0 30.1 30.2 30.3 30.4 30.5 30.6 30.7 30.8 30.9 31.0 31.1 31.2 31.3 31.4
[16] 31.5 31.6 31.7 31.8 31.9 32.0
```

Agora basta colocar este comando dentro da função `axis` do teu código:

```
t_mean = c(30.24, 30.73, 30.94, 31.97, 31.28, 31.84, 31.56, 32.00)
time   = c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14)

plot(t_mean~time, type ="l",  ylim=c(30.0,32), yaxt ="n")
axis(2, at=seq(from=30, to=32, by=0.1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atenção: dependendo do tamanho da tela do teu computador ou da resolução dela, pode ser que não apareçam todos os números desejados ao rodar o código que passei. Veja o que acontece quando eu gero esta mesma imagem no meu computador, que tem tela de 13 polegadas e sem utilizar zoom:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que os números não estão mais variando de 0.2 em 0.2, mas sim de 0.3 em 0.3. Se eu quisesse que a variação fosse idêntica à definida originalmente, de 0.1 em 0.1, eu terei que, obrigatoriamente, reduzir a fonte do gráfico através da função `par` com o argumento `cex` apropriado:

```
par(cex=.5)
plot(t_mean~time, type ="l",  ylim=c(30.0,32), yaxt ="n")
axis(2, at=seq(from=30, to=32, by=0.1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que todos os valores decimais entre 30 e 32 apareceram, mas a visualização não ficou boa. É dever de quem está produzindo o gráfico decidir qual é a melhor maneira de apresentá-lo. Nenhuma das três que apresentei aqui está errada, mas na minha opinião, a primeira (variando de 0.2 em 0.2) é a melhor.

Comment: Há ainda o parâmetro gráfico `las`. Com `las = 2` costuma haver espaço para todos os valores. (Tentei `axis(..., las = 2)` e deu.)